# { "message": "invalid input syntax for type integer: \"12 Pro\"" } Below error appears while trying to send POST request with PostgreSQL

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

Error appears while trying to send POST request with PostgreSQL/Sequelize what could be the problem here?

```
  async create(req, res, next) {
    try {
      let { name, price, brandId, typeId, info } = req.body;
      const { img } = req.files;
      let fileName = uuid.v4() + ".jpg";
      img.mv(path.resolve(__dirname, "..", "static", fileName));
      const device = await Device.create({
        name,
        price,
        brandId,
        typeId,
        img: fileName,
      });

      return res.json(device);
    } catch (e) {
      next(ApiError.badRequest(e.message));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Well `12 Pro` does not look like an integer to me.

Answer (score 0):

The error checks are failing: You are providing a string where an Integer is expected. What causes it is uncertain unless you provide the interface for `Device.create()`. Check the docs and make sure your input data has the correct types.

*EDIT: The following thoughts were bogus* <strike>There might also be a mix-up with your input: When using the shorthand object notation as you did, make sure your arguments have the right order. Depending on framework your input might just be wrong syntax, because you are essentially initializing an object with no keys but `img`. If your framework doesn't correct that, this might also be the error source.</strike>

But again, without further information on what the function call expects and what type your arguments have, debugging is fortune telling.

Comment: The shorthand object initializer syntax uses the mentioned variable names as the object property names, so the object does have keys; it doesn't make sense for an object to have property values without property names.

Comment: Ok,so that point is moot.

Comment: Here is the model and type is STRING `const Device = sequelize.define("device", {
  id: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true },
  name: { type: DataTypes.STRING, unique: true, allowNull: false },
  price: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, allowNull: false },
  rating: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, defaultValue: 0 },
  img: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
});`

Comment: So my guess would be that `price` is the one causing the error since that's the only key that you've provided that need to be an integer. What does your example say about the type and value of said variable?

Comment: Changed type to STRING but still an error appearing. My example?